# Parse XML string returned from service with C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse the following XML string that is being returned from a service.

```
 DataReference.USZipSoapClient blah = new DataReference.USZipSoapClient("USZipSoap");
        var results = blah.GetInfoByCity(tbCityName.Text).OuterXml;
```

returns the following

```
<NewDataSet xmlns=""><Table><CITY>Marana</CITY><STATE>AZ</STATE><ZIP>85653</ZIP><AREA_CODE>520</AREA_CODE><TIME_ZONE>M</TIME_ZONE></Table></NewDataSet>
```

I'm having no luck parsing the data:

I just want to display the results like **City = Marana, State = AZ** etc.

Comment: Parsing XML files is a mature problem and is documented all over the place. I suggest you start by reading about `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`.

Comment: Well what have you *tried* to parse the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use XPath?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(results); // probably some try-catch here
var city = doc.SelectSingleNode("//CITY").InnerXml; //Handle null as well
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a serializing object and then serialize the data you get against that object, i used http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ to generate the following xml object:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Table")]
public class Table {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="CITY")]
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="STATE")]
    public string STATE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="ZIP")]
    public string ZIP { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="AREA_CODE")]
    public string AREA_CODE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="TIME_ZONE")]
    public string TIME_ZONE { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="NewDataSet")]
public class NewDataSet {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Table")]
    public Table Table { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}
```

Then just use the .net XML serializer to cast it to that object and use it in your code.

Comment: That's a very interesting service. Thank you for this info!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a string for visual inspection, a first step could be to convert the XMl to JSON with this code:
http://techhasnoboundary.blogspot.no/2011/08/convert-xml-to-json-using-c.html

Then you could go on by removing braces, replace comma with line break and colon with an equal sign.